# Get "'http_proxy' had unsupported trailing garbage" from .curlrc

Tags: curl

For the longest time, whenever I execute "curl", I get the following:

```
/home/me/.curlrc:1: warning: 'http_proxy' had unsupported trailing garbage
Warning: /home/me/.curlrc:2: warning: 'https_proxy' had unsupported
Warning: trailing garbage
```

My ~/.curlrc file just has this:

```
http_proxy = "http://<ourproxyhost>:8080"
```

I've tried several variations of this, without quotes or spaces in particular.

Searching the internet for this, it seems like a FAQ, but the only "answer" that I've seen anywhere says to change "http_proxy" to "proxy".  Doing that sort of works, as I no longer get the warning, but now curl completely fails to access internal sites (even though external sites appear to still work).

I've verified this behavior on both Cygwin and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “answer” you’ve found is correct, the proxy configuration setting for `curl` is `proxy`, not `http_proxy`. The error message is rather unclear...

The behaviour you see when you set `proxy` is fairly common in enterprise settings: your proxy doesn’t support internal sites, so you need to configure your proxy-using tools to ignore the proxy for internal sites (this is the setup commonly done using `proxy.pac`). To set this up, you’ll need to use the `noproxy` option, and specify a comma-separated list of hosts and/or domains for which the proxy shouldn’t be used.